# Change Android emulator http proxy AFTER launching avd with command line

Tags: android, bash, android-emulator

How can I change emulator proxy **on the fly**? I know I can use `-http-proxy` argument for defining proxy server when I start an emulator (or use `http_proxy` environment variable), But I want to change proxy server of a booted and running emulator **from the command line**.

AVD options panel (`Extended Controls`) makes it possible to define http proxy on the fly.

[image: Extended Controls Screenshot]

So the question is "What is the command line way to do so"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `adb shell settings put global http_proxy <ip>:<port>`. but remember it only works if your application didn't specify the proxy.(No Proxy or etc)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should remove `NO_PROXY` from `Retrofit` config for debugging app

Answer (score 3):

You can set [HTTP_PROXY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global#HTTP_PROXY) global setting with next command:

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy <ip>:<port>
```

Comment: Does this works even if an my application uses `NO_PROXY` config?